# Not able to login when added spring security in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have given the configuration in application.properties file as:

```
spring.security.user.name=root  
spring.security.user.password=root
```

My security configuration class is:

```
package com.ashwin.rws.basic.auth;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin().and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

My main class is:

```
package com.ashwin.rws;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestfulWebServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestfulWebServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My rest controller is:

```
package com.ashwin.rws.rest.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ashwin.rws.model.HelloWorldBean;

@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {


    @GetMapping(path="/hello-world")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/hello-world-bean")  
    public HelloWorldBean helloWorldBean() {
        //throw new RuntimeException("Some error has occured.Contact service");
        return new HelloWorldBean("Hello world-changed");
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/hello-world/path-variable/{name}")  
    public HelloWorldBean helloWorldBeanPathVariable(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        System.out.print("name is"+name);
        return new HelloWorldBean(String.format("Hello world %s", name));
    }

}
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ashwin.rws</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-web-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restful-web-services</name>
    <description>Restful web services</description>

    <properties>
         <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Suppose when I type localhost:8080/ then login screen appears at first and when I try to login using the username and password as root then it is saying me **Bad credentials** and the URL is redirected to **http://localhost:8080/login?error** .It is not giving me to login ,though I typed correct username and password

Comment: BTW: I see that you are using Java 11, try Java 8.

Comment: i installed latest eclipse and also made project from spring.io but if i didnt put any default username and password and use the generate password given by spring security then login is success but if i use the spring.security.user.name=user 
spring.security.user.password=user in application.properties it is saing me bad credintals

Comment: @ashwinkarki do you have any in-memory user?

Answer (score 0):

remove `.and().httpBasic();` part and you should be okay.

Comment: what about formlogin()

Comment: you should keep `formLogin` if you want to see the default Spring Security login page.